# Why my service is still working when app is closed and screen is locked

Tags: android, service

Always when I was creating service that was supposed to for example listen to changes on server I've been always using `AlarmManager` and `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to poll server every now and then because when I tried to do in with infinite loop inside Service it would stop once screen was locked.
But recently In my Service I was checking location with `LocationListener`. I wasn't using AlarmManager for this because location was supposed to be checked only once but I've forgotten to remove the listener after use and noticed it is still working even when I close the app and lock the screen. Could somebody explain to me why is that? I thought that Service should stop when screen is locked

Comment: "Service should stop when screen is locked" who told you that. service only gets paused

Comment: Ok, you are right. But still, how my service get location updates when paused?

Comment: its actually very specific to android versions. I've myself struggled a lot with services and stuff. on android < 6 your service would be active. above 6, the new doze mode kills all that activity. but again, its distributor specific as well

Answer (score 0):

Set START_NOT_STICKY in service class.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() called with: intent = [" + intent + "], 

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```